Is there a relationship between keyboard and display manager?
I have a keyboard problem (= random erratic behavior) that does not appear in the following logs: kernel logs (dmesg), /var/log/journal (journalctl) or /var/log/Xorg.0.log [less Xorg.0.log | grep -i keyboard].
The last time the problem occurred, instead of rebooting, I opened a tty2 console as root and restarted lightdm, the display manager. When the display was restored, the keyboard was no longer erratic: it behaved completely normally.
Is there anything to learn from this strange behavior?

The keyboard has a builtin microprocessor, type depending on which choice the producer has made. Your restart of the display manager may well include a reset of the keyboard's builtin software, "a reboot" in effect.  Try find a replacement keyboard to use, see if that eliminates the problem..

I think I can test this hypothesis by running the chvt 7 command from tty2. I should return to my normal environment without restarting lightdm.
